# Sealing Crape Myrtles to stop new growth

Tags: pruning

I've removed a lot of limbs from the bottom of my crape myrtles, to limit it to a few odd numbered limbs. However, where the cuts were made continue to put forth new growth, that I don't want. Is there anything I can seal these areas with to stop new growth? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

It is not recommended that you use any kind of wound sealant on cut limbs of a tree. Latex paint is included on that list - you run the risk of sealing in moisture, along with bacterial and fungal life forms which may cause disease in your trees. The paint will also prevent the formation of a callus, a necessary part of the process to heal the wound, see this article: [Is Outdoor Latex Paint an Effective Sealer for Pruning?](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/outdoor-latex-paint-effective-sealer-pruning-95767.html).

Inevitably, cut limbs will produce new shoots, more so if the  pruning is carried out before July in the northern hemisphere - the only thing you can do is check the tree frequently and rub out any small buds of growth before they break into growth, or cut off new growth as it appears.

Answer (score 2):

There are various growth inhibitors you might look it, but best case scenario they are temporary.  I haven't every used any of them, so I can't recommend a product.

In generally the best you can do is:

- prune shoots as early as possible
- make flush cuts (don't leave stubs)
- remove any stubs you do have that are making multiple shoots